# Largest solution of a linear system

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, eigenvalues-eigenvectors, singular-values

Given an $n\times m$ matrix $A$ of full-column rank, and a vector $\vec b$ of size $n$.
We consider the solution of the linear system:
$$
A\vec{x}=\vec{b}
$$
Since $A$ is full-column rank, the solutions of the linear system are bounded. Is it possible to get an upper bound on the norm of these solutions ?

Comment: If $A$ has full column rank, then $A\vec{x}=\vec{b}$ has no more than one solution. As I noted in my answer, one can obtain a lower bound on the norms of the solutions without rank assumptions.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Suppose that $A\vec{x}=\vec{b}$ is solvable.

Unless $A$ has full column rank, the system $A\vec{x}=\vec{b}$ has infinitely many solutions. The set
$$
\{\lVert\vec{x}\rVert:A\vec{x}=\vec{b}\}
$$
turns out to be bounded below, but not above. In fact, it is possible to prove that 
$$
\inf\{\lVert\vec{x}\rVert:A\vec{x}=\vec{b}\}=\lVert\vec{x}^+\rVert
$$
Here, $\vec{x}^+=A^+\vec{b}$ where $A^+$ is the *[Moore-Penrose inverse](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Moore-Penrose_inverse)* or *pseudoinverse* of $A$. The vector $\vec{x}^+$ also satisfies $A\vec{x}^+=\vec{b}$.

Note that this is true regardless of the rank of $A$.

To convince yourself that $\{\lVert\vec{x}\rVert:A\vec{x}=\vec{b}\}$ is not bounded above, consider
\begin{align*}
A &= \left[\begin{array}{rrr}
1 & 0 & 0 \\
0 & 1 & 0
\end{array}\right] & \vec{b} &= \left[\begin{array}{r}
0 \\
0
\end{array}\right]
\end{align*}
The solutions to $A\vec{x}=\vec{b}$ are  of the form 
$$
\vec{x}
= \left[\begin{array}{r}
0 \\
0 \\
c
\end{array}\right]
$$
for $c\in\Bbb R$.

Comment: sorry, the first version of the question wasn't making sense...